# jQuery scroll event continually firing scroll function

Tags: jquery

so I'm trying to make a couple divs scroll to a certain spot in their content when the user scrolls. Here is my current code:

```
var target = 0;
var main_scroll = 0;    
var top_scroll = 0; 
var bot_scroll = 0; 
var counter = 1;

$('.main-container').on('scroll', function() {
    if ($('#trigger-' + (counter + 1)).length && $(this).scrollTop() > target) {                
        main_scroll = main_scroll + $('.main-container').height();          
        $('.main-container').animate({              
            scrollTop: main_scroll              
        }, 1000);

        top_scroll = top_scroll + $('.top-container').height();         
        $('.top-container').animate({               
            scrollTop: top_scroll               
        }, 1000);

        bot_scroll = bot_scroll + $('.bottom-container').height();          
        $('.bottom-container').animate({                
            scrollTop: bot_scroll               
        }, 1000);

        target = target + $('.main-container').height();            
        counter++;            
    } else if ($('#trigger-' + (counter - 1)).length && $(this).scrollTop() < target) {
        main_scroll = main_scroll - $('.main-container').height();              
        $('.main-container').animate({              
            scrollTop: main_scroll              
        }, 1000);

        top_scroll = top_scroll - $('.top-container').height();             
        $('.top-container').animate({               
            scrollTop: top_scroll               
        }, 1000);

        bot_scroll = bot_scroll - $('.bottom-container').height();          
        $('.bottom-container').animate({                
            scrollTop: bot_scroll               
        }, 1000);

        target = target - $('.main-container').height();            
        counter--;              
    }        
});
```

As it stands right now, if I scroll once the divs continually bounce up and down. Not 100% sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: A working example would help a lot here, either in a snippet or a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to fix this by using:

```
if ( ! $(this).is(':animated') ) {
```

to make sure that the scroll event wasn't being fired by my animation.